# Extending EF Poco Class

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, poco

I am learning EF 4 staff and really got stacked.  I am using Code First approach eg.

```
public class Machine{
 public int A{get;set;}
 ...
}
```

I am trying to implement business logic in additional property based on the A property (eg. B = A+5) and present it in WPF datagrid. This new property doesn't need to be stored in database at all. How would I do that (e.g. with partial class )? Any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Machine
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int B
    {
        get
        {
            return A + 5;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thats great, but how could I implement an INotifyPropertyChanged which will be fired in  public int A
        {
            get { return a; }
            set { 
                a = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("A");
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("C");
                
            }
        }

Comment: Yes, you have to set off OnPropertyChanged("B") in the setter of A because otherwise the UI won't recalculate B. I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF 4.1 you can just use the [not mapped attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). If you are using the edmx designer, i beleive you can remove the column name it assigns to in the model viewer table mappings

Comment: I am adding an scalar property after I map it to database. Then I got an erro :The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication4.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9

Comment: are your entity classes implementing inotify ?